# ODBC Connection to Multiple Oracle Servers (Listener.ora config.)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener, tnsnames

I hope that you can help me out with this issue.

I currently have a connection to an Oracle server for which I had to set up a listener.ora and TNSNames.ora file.

I created these files using 'Net Configuration Assistant' (OraClient11g64).

I now want to set up a connection to an additional Oracle server using the same method.  I haven't created a new listener as I don't believe that is necessary(?), but I have gone through the steps for 'Local Net Service Name config.' with no luck.

My error message on test is -

> TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

I suspect my listener is configured wrong, but need a little help.

'listener.ora' is as follows -

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: 
c:\oraclexxx\product64\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXXXXXX.wks.xxx.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = c:\oraclexxx
```

I've replaced identifiable info with X.  I believe there ought to be more to this file.  Some SID list stuff?  But it currently works on my single connection and the assistant doesn't seem to make it any different.

Current TNSNames file that I hoped the assistant would change -

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: 
c:\oraclexxx\product64\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

xxxxxx2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxx04.xxx.com)(PORT = 1531))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = xxxxxx2)
    )
  )
```

These two files are currently working for my original Oracle server, but the listener doesn't like when I try to create a connection to the new one.  The new server is on port 1521 if that makes a difference.  I notice that currently my connection and listener are on different ports but work ok.

How can I best configure these files.  I've searched all around the net but am a bit lost and don't want to risk breaking my current connection.

May also be worth mentioning that Oracle SQL Developer connects to both without issue.

Comment: The *client* doesn't need a listener at all. The servers will each have a listener; your `tnsnames.ora` then has an entry for each of the databases on those servers that you need to connect to, with specific IP addresses, ports (probably 1521 but not necessarily), and service names (or possibly SIDs but service names are preferred) for those databases. You can use the basic connection info you've already got working in SQL Developer in a new TNS entry in that file, manually or through netca. Assuming you actually need TNS connections at all...

Comment: I do need the TNS as I'm using R to interact with the servers.  The problem is that when I use netca and test the connection, it fails.  I'll try to add the new details onto the 'tnsnames.ora' file manually and see if that works.

Comment: You need the service name from the new remote server's listener. If you can connect from SQL Developer is that connection specifying the service name or the SID? They might not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from global_name;
```

I ran this on my new database and the Service Name was a little different from the expected.

ABC.xxx.com rather than just ABC.

Connection test worked in NetCA.  Both connection tests now fail when configuring 'Data Sources (ODBC)' but they seem to actually be working ok in R.

Thanks for leading me in the right direction @Alex Poole